# Table of contents of several chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I know that package `minitoc` is able to generate an individual chapter table of contents (ToC) by each one, however, i´d like to get a table of contents of several chapters together (I´m using report).

For example, this is my full ToC:

[image]

And I´d like to get this additional ToC separately (with its own format, etc):
[image]

Can someone please help me to get this result?

Thank you.

Comment: Something like `\parttoc`?

Comment: Maybe, but I dont know how to solve with it. I have read about `\parttoc` in several posts, but I didn´t find the way to do what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution using `\parttoc`. I let the code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}

\begin{document}

\doparttoc

\tableofcontents

\part{I. MEMORIA}
\parttoc

\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section1.1}
\chapter{Chapter2}
\section{Section2.1}

\end{document}
```

Using that piece of code, it can be a solution.